# Why the command aws iam list-users not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

`aws iam list-users` command not working

[image: Env variable window]

[image: aws iam list-users cmd]

I have setup AWS CLI in Windows. The path has been added under the system environment variable.

When I try the commands `aws --version` and `aws configure`, it is successful. But to see the list of users the command `aws iam list-users` is throwing this error:

> 'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I am stuck. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the AWS CLI is trying to use an **output paginator** that is not in the path.

Put simply, AWS CLI sends its output via a utility that lets you 'page' through the results. In your case, it is trying to use the [more](https://linuxhint.com/linux-more-command-with-examples/) command.

You can tell the AWS CLI *not* to use a paginator by putting this in the `.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

For more details, see: [Using AWS CLI pagination options - Client-side pager - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html#cli-usage-pagination-clientside)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:  aws iam list-users > output.txt